# Itextpdf error while decrypting a pdf using pkcs11 usb token

Tags: java, security, encryption, certificate, itext

I am using iTextpdf to decrypt a PDF which is encrypted with certificate.

Following exception occurs while decrypting.

```
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: exception unwrapping key: key invalid: unknown key type passed to RSA
```

Following is my code snippet

```
    public void decryptPdf(String src, String dest)
        throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException,CMSException {
        try{
//        decrypt(getPrivateKey(), DESTINATION_FILE, DECRYPTED_FILE);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src,
            getPublicCertificate("C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\test\\src\\lk_encb64.cer"), getPrivateKey(), "BC");
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

Method getPrivateKey() returns my private key from PKCS11-eTocken

```
public PrivateKey getPrivateKey() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

        LoggerFactory.getInstance().setLogger(new SysoLogger());

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileInputStream("D:/key.properties"));
        char[] pass = properties.getProperty("PASSWORD").toCharArray();

    String config = "name=eToken\n" +
                "library=" + DLL + "\n";
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(config.getBytes());
    Provider providerPKCS11 = new SunPKCS11(bais);
        Security.addProvider(providerPKCS11);
        System.out.println(providerPKCS11.getName());

    BouncyCastleProvider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(providerBC);

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
        ks.load(null, pass);
        String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();

        java.util.Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();


        alias = aliases.nextElement();

        System.out.println("testing key....");
        System.out.println(alias);
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, pass);
        System.out.println(pk);
        return pk;
    }
```

Method getPublicCertificate() is as follows

```
public Certificate getPublicCertificate(String path)
        throws IOException, CertificateException {
        System.out.println(path);
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\test\\src\\lk_encb64.cer");
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is);
        return cert;
    }
```

i have used following jar versions

itext 5.5.10

bcprov jdk15 on 1.49

bcpkix jdk15 on 1.49

Comment: The exception says "key invalid". Thus, the method `getPrivateKey()` and what it returns are of interest.

Comment: Kindly find the method getPrivateKey()

Comment: System.out.println(pk) shows SunPKCS11-eToken RSA private key, 2048 bits (id 2, token object, sensitive, extractable)

Comment: As the key is not generated by BouncyCastle but by the SunPKCS11 provider, have you tried replacing the `"BC"` parameter of the `PdfReader` constructor call by the name of the SunPKCS11 provider? You already output that name using `System.out.println(providerPKCS11.getName())` in `getPrivateKey`...

Comment: @mkl Thanks u so much. i changed code as PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src,
            getPublicCertificate("C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\test\\src\\lk_encb64.cer"), getPrivateKey(), "SunPKCS11-eToken"); now i am getting  error **com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: cannot create cipher: No such algorithm: 1.2.840.113549.3.2**

Comment: @mkl now it is working with itext 5.2.1 bcprov 1.46 and bcmail 1.46. Thanks a lot. Why it is not working with bc 1.49?

Comment: Hhmmm, if it worked for 5.2.1 and does not anymore for 5.5.10, that looks like a regression. Unfortunately I do not have such an etoken, so I cannot test and investigate.

Comment: @mkl Thank you so much for your support and direction

Comment: @mkl i am getting an error "com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: key invalid in message." while decrypting  a pdf with pkcs11 token which is already encrypted with adobe dc pro. Thanks in advance

Comment: This appears to be a different issue than the question here, so please make it a separate stack overflow question. Furthermore, answering this question might require you to share a sample PDF for inspection.

Comment: @mkl [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611353/com-itextpdf-text-exceptions-invalidpdfexception-key-invalid-in-message-when-de)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611353/com-itextpdf-text-exceptions-invalidpdfexception-key-invalid-in-message-when-de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed the code with provider name "SunPKCS11-eToken" instead of "BC" as suggested by @mkl

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src, getPublicCertificate("C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\NetBeansPr‌​ojects\\test\\src\\l‌​k_encb64.cer"), getPrivateKey(), "SunPKCS11-eToken");
```

and used itext 5.2.1 and bc 1.46 version ([decryption/encryption using BC 1.46 an iText 5.2.1 is working fine](http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Error-on-PDF-decryption-td4658603.html)) jars , and now the decryption working fine.

Comment: @mkl i am getting an error "com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: key invalid in message." while decrypting  a pdf with pkcs11 token which is already encrypted with adobe dc pro. Thanks in advance