# com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: key invalid in message when decrypting pdf encrypted with adobe dc pro using pkcss11 usb token

Tags: java, pdf, encryption, itext, bouncycastle

I am using iTextpdf to encrypt/decrypt  PDF using pkcss11 usb token certificate.

Following is my encrypt and decrypt methods

```
public void encryptPdf(String src, String dest)
        throws IOException, DocumentException, CertificateException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        Certificate cert = getPublicCertificate("C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\test\\src\\lk_enc.cer");
        stamper.setEncryption(new Certificate[]{cert},
            new int[]{PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING}, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }

public void decryptPdf(String src, String dest)
        throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException,CMSException {
        try{
//        decrypt(getPrivateKey(), DESTINATION_FILE, DECRYPTED_FILE);
            PrivateKey pkc = getPrivateKey();
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src,
            getPublicCertificate("C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\test\\src\\lk_enc.cer"), pkc, "SunPKCS11-eToken");
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

I am using itextpdf 5.2.1 and bc 1.46 versions. Decryption works fine with pdf encrypted using encryptPdf() method.

But decryptPdf() mehtod fails with error
**com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: key invalid in message**
 when using  a pdf which is encrypted with Adobe dc pro (128 AES) as source file .

Source PDFs

[1.PDF encrypted with  encryptPdf() method](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-3hLfWwMOZ_aWU5VnBqdFlzY0U)

[2.PDF encrypted with adobe dc pro with AES 128bit](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-3hLfWwMOZ_RlNxX3N3MndNUnlYWjgzb1Q4UlFyX2w1dHpr)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hhmm, the Adobe file has a **R** value of 131105 in its encryption dictionary. According to the PDF specification ISO 32000-1 only values 2, 3, and 4 are allowed. Probably Adobe already uses an encryption type from the soon to be published ISO 32000-2 which iText does not understand?

Comment: @mkl that means there is no way to decrypt a pdf encrypted with Adobe dc pro using iText 5.2.1.Is n't it?

Comment: Well, it is my assumption that that uncommon value is an early 2.0 adaption. It might also be a bug. The jump appears large...

Comment: @mkl I have used a trial version of Adobe dc pro.

Comment: Actually I'm waiting for the final PDF 2.0 specification to be published. Before that I can only guess as I'm not part of the ISO committee responsible.